# How do I generate a nodeset from the results of a function that yields another type?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

Consider the following xml:

```
<days>
    <day><temperature>40 F</temperature></day>
    <day><temperature>45 F</temperature></day>
    <day><temperature>50 F</temperature></day>
</days>
```

I'd like to calculate an average temperature by summing the temperatures and then dividing by the count.  Getting a value for the count is easy:

```
count(/days/day/temperature)
```

If the numbers had no units, getting the sum would also be easy:

```
sum(/days/day/temperature)
```

However, to sum this, first I need to remove the units.  Simple enough, just use translate to get rid of the unwanted unit, for example

```
/days/day/temperature/translate(.,' F', '')
```

This works.  But because it returns a list of numbers instead of a nodeset, I can't use the result in the sum function.  How do I get a translated nodeset so that I can calculate that sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum(/days/day/temperature/number(translate(., ' F', '')))` to compute the sum. It has nothing to do with node-sets however, those are part of the XSLT/XPath 1.0 data model, in XSLT/XPath 2.0 or XQuery you simply need to make sure you call `sum` on a sequence of number values.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like the lack of a number cast was exactly what was holding me back.